# A problem Understanding how a two-body system of planets starts rotating around barycentre

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, planets, relative-motion

Consider,We are Creating a Two-body system in free space,Where no other mass exists,Let's Take First Mass M1 and hold it,Now bring Second Mass M2,hold it up,Now we are giving a suddenly impulse To M1 causing its initial Velocity to be V1 and then releasing M2,now here,How do we derive that These bodies will perform Circular motion About (Barycentre/Centre of masses),What will happen between The the time When Impulse is given and time When They become steady rotating about Centre Of mass(in COM frame).

The Gravitational force is only considered here,So my Question is Centrepetal Force Acts on both which varies inversely to $r^2$,So How are they set into circular motion?

Answer (score 1):

In your model, there is no expectation of circular motion.

The usual theoretical understanding is that planets form from gas and dust in an accretion disk. The gas and dust in a disk moves in nearly circular orbits: frictional effects (not considered in your model) are assumed to damp radial motion. The planets (initially) share that motion.

Comment: ,Can you please share Some links to understand these theories,Besides my doubt is,How Did planets managed to get the Exact velocity and distance to be in circular motion(Somewhat elliptical),I mean For slight larger Gravitational force between system might Cause them to move Toward each other?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protoplanetary_disk

Answer (score 1):

Planets and stars are formed from **already rotating** protoplanetary disk of dust and gas, from which planets "borrow" angular speed. Of course there's still question remains - how and when (presumably first) protoplanetary disks acquired angular momentum ? I believe root causes lies in Navier-Stokes equations and turbulence. Dust/Gas mass in the galaxy is affected randomly by local gravitational sources (many-body problem), which produces friction between layers of dust, and consequently - relative angular motion and turbulence, which fragments dust into disks.

Comment: Cany you please Elaborate on,"They borrowed The angular momentum",I understand that The Disks were formed Due to relative angular momentum,how does that caused the planets to revolve around common barycentre?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Disk has friction between layers and turbulence, thus this fragments disk into inner rotating clumps of dust/gas from which bi-planet system is evolved.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity $\mathbf v_1$ of $M_1$ must be such that there is not radial component when $M_2$ is released. If this condition is fulfilled, there is a specific $|\mathbf v_1|$  for a circular orbit.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to indicate that you think of the rotational motion around the barycentre as some stationary state the two-body system reaches after some short time after the initial conditions are set, and only at that point is it possible to speak about circular motion.

This is not the way Newtonian mechanics works. The rotation starts as soon as the two bodies are set at their initial positions with their initial velocities. However, to have it, not all the initial conditions are good. If you put the two bodies at any distance with zero speeds or with non-zero collinear velocities, their motion will remain confined to a line segment. This is a consequence of starting with zero (conserved) angular momentum. Instead, the angular momentum is different from zero if the initial velocities are not aligned with the relative position vector. In such conditions, the motion remains confined in a plane. Still, the trajectories of the two bodies immediately start to *bend* as a consequence of the existence of an acceleration not aligned with the velocity.

Then, for a general attractive force between the two bodies, it is possible to show that the motion in the system frame where the center of mass is at rest will remain confined in the region between two concentric circles (annulus). In general, the trajectory will fill this region densely, but for the Newtonian forces with intensity proportional to $\frac{1}{r^2}$, the trajectory is a closed ellipse in general.

I stress that such behavior is something characterizing the motion immediately from the starting conditions. It is not some final stage of the motion.

Comment: let's say ,The planets have Initial Velocity vectors ,Not aligned with Attractive force,So they will start moving toward each other as well as rotate w.r.t Centre of mass,How to show the motion will end up Being circular w.r.t Centre of mass,I mean When attractive force GMm/r^2>M(v1)^2,then In frame of centre of mass,planet will move towards COM as well as In tangential direction,Which is not circular motion initially w.r.t. COM,Can you share any links showing These derivations?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi  The circular motion is a very special case. The most common case is that there will be an elliptic orbit of both bodies around the center of mass. In order to suggest you a link or to show the derivation, it would be useful to know what is your knowledge background.

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi However, from what you write, I would guess that you need to get a better understanding of Newtonian mechanics, before discussing the gravitational two-body system. In general, it is not true that two bodies with a purely attractive force between them will start moving toward each other. There will be an infinite set of initial conditions such that initially, they will move away from each other. For example, think of a stone thrown toward the sky.

Comment: I am In Grade 12,Currently preparing for IITJEE Engineering entrance exam,what are prerequisites for understanding those derivations?I have studied Newtonian mechanics Quite well,But I am having hard time,visualising how those planets got in Elliptical Motion Initially